# Excel VBA to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am converting some codes from `Excel VBA` to `C#` and run into this problem. I am not sure the equivalent of this code in c#. `Intellisence` wasn't very helpful :(

`Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments.Item(1) = 90`

I managed to get as far as `Adjustment` in c# but there is no `Item` property.

Comment: If you look in the object browser `.Item` is the default property of the `Adjustments` collection. In most cases a default property on a collection in VBA is equivalent to an indexer in C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/microsoft.office.interop.excel.adjustments.item) it seems the `Adjustments` property has an indexer, so you could do this:

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Adjustments[1] = 90;
```